# Sublime Text 3: how to bind a shortcut to a specific file extension?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to customize shortcut, but apply them only to a specific extension.

For example,

"jump to matching bracket" -> works in JS files -> customly bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>,

"go to matching tag pair" (emmet) -> works in HTML files -> I would like to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> also here, but doesn't work (ST3 understand "jump to matching bracket" which doesn't apply here).

I was wondering if specializing a shortcut to a specific extension would do the trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently you can try something like this:

`[
   { "keys": ["ctrl+x", "ctrl+i"], 
     "command": "insert_snippet", 
     "args": {"name": "Packages/User/mysnippet.sublime-snippet"},
     "context": [ {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"} ]
   }
]`

Where you'ld replace the first 3 lines by what you want, and `text.tex.latex` by the scope you want (source.js and text.html.basic in your case).

Comment: how I do for bind only on php file for exmeple?

Comment: @Matrix I honestly haven’t used sublime in a while. But a quick google search indicates maybe embedding.php ?