# Sublime Text 3 - apply shortcut only to specific file types

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text 3, and I installed `JSFormat` to format my `.js` files and configured the key binding like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "js_format" }
```

Now, I also want to be able to format my `.css` and `.html` files, so I found this shortcut:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "reindent" , "args": { "single_line": false } }
```

I want to use `js_format` for my `.js` files and use `reindent` for my `.css` and `.html` files.

Is it possible to specify a file type per shortcut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3: how to bind a shortcut to a specific file extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268340/sublime-text-3-how-to-bind-a-shortcut-to-a-specific-file-extension)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

This apparently no longer works in Sublime Text 4.

### Update

I've since discovered that this is a duplicate of [Sublime Text 3: how to bind a shortcut to a specific file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268340/sublime-text-3-how-to-bind-a-shortcut-to-a-specific-file-extension)

### Original Answer

Add a `context`:

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"],
  "command": "js_format",
  "context": [
    {
      "key": "selector",
      "operator": "equal",
      "operand": "source.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

The important part is setting `operand` to `source.js`. You can replace `js` with whatever file extension you want. You can also specify additional sources with commas. For example, this would cause a command to apply to all `.html` and `.css` files:

```
{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.html, source.css" }
```

See the [unofficial documentation on key bindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html).

Comment: Hey this doesn't work anymore in sublime text 4. Is there an updated version of it

Comment: @risingStark Unfortunately I don't use Sublime Text anymore, so I don't know.

Comment: thanks for the heads up

Comment: here is the working version for me on sublime text 4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857676/1020512